# highcharts column graph with dynamic data- column alignment off

Tags: highcharts

i'm hoping that this quick description and image will ring a bell with someone who has had a similar issue and therefore a suggestion/fix.

i have a column graph that i am adding data to dynamically (via jQuery parsing an XML file).

for some reason, after the data is added, the alignment of the different series gets a little off. the issue fixes itself after i toggle one of the series by being visible/invisible (by clicking the series in the legend).

when i add the data via hardcoding the numbers, just to ensure it works, it works great.

here is the image:
[image]

the yellow series is the last series added to the chart, the red and purple series line up ok after toggling the visibility of one of the 5 series.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE with info on the data:**

- i have 5 series of data and 10 x-axis categories
- i am building a multidimensional array of data as i parse the XML file
- the array length is 5, with each of those 5 index's containing an array of length 10
- this is what the array looks like after it has been populated with data:

index#: 0 value: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

index#: 1 value: 180,210,0,0,0,0,0,0,180,210

index#: 2 value: 22,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,22,4

index#: 3 value: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

index#: 4 value: 200,30,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0

i am adding the data to the chart with the following JS code:

```
for (var c_ary_bs = 0; c_ary_bs < ary_bs_schedule_orig.length; c_ary_bs++) {
        chart.series[c_ary_bs].setData(ary_bs_schedule_orig[c_ary_bs]);
    }
```

hopefully that will help, thank you!

**UPDATE 2, some more info**

i've hard coded the data being added to the array, to help pinpoint the issue:

```
    chart.series[0].setData([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
    chart.series[1].setData([180, 210, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 180, 210]);
    chart.series[2].setData([22, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 4]);
    chart.series[3].setData([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
    chart.series[4].setData([200, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0]);
    alert('done')
```

when the alert fires, the graph columns are aligned properly, after I click "ok" to dismiss the alert, the alignment issue happens, as the previous image depicts.

Comment: Can you post some data that is causing this?  Even better would be creating an example on jsfiddle.

Comment: @malonso thank you for your time, I've updated my question with info on the data

Comment: I really wish I could give you an answer but it definitely looks like this could be a bug.  Not to take traffic away from SO but I might suggest posting on the HC forum (http://highslide.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=8); Torstein and his group are great and usually quite response.  Sorry, wish I had better news.

Comment: it's all good @malonso , thank you for your time. i agree it seems like a bug. at least i was able to move on with the 'imperfect fix'. best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I found an imperfect fix:

-setting the marginLeft of the chart to 70 alleviates the issue with the columns not aligning

-for some reason the y-axis title text is displaying over the y-axis ticks, so i am using the following to make it visible:

```
 yAxis: {
        title: {
            x:-20,
            text: 'Schedule Days'
        }
    }
```

(note the x: -20)

Whats's odd is that when I toggle one of the series (by clicking it in the legend) the yAxis title text reverts to where it should be (which is now 20px off because of the above fix).

The perfect fix would put the yAxis text where it is after I toggle one of the series, but at least this way it is now visible regardless of whether or not the user toggles the series.